# Does NSValue free its value when freed?

Tags: objective-c, pointers, memory-management, nsvalue

Have a look at this pseudocode:

```
void* magicpointer = malloc(OVER_NINE_THOUSAND);
NSValue* v = [NSValue valueWithPointer:magicpointer];
[v release];
```

When v is released, does magicpointer get freed as well, or do I have to do that manually? I am using manual reference counting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't get freed - NSValue is just a wrapper so you can treat arbitrary values as objects. It doesn't do anything with the wrapped pointer.

Answer (score 5):

No, `NSValue` won't.

Sounds like you might want to use `NSData`, it can free it's pointer when it's released:

```
    void* magicpointer = malloc(OVER_NINE_THOUSAND);
    NSData *d = [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:magicpointer
                                     length:OVER_NINE_THOUSAND
                               freeWhenDone:YES];
    //d is autoreleased, so no need to -release it.
```

Comment: Much more useful answer since it introduces an alternative way, thanks Vincent!

Answer (score 1):

NSValue does not free the pointer when the NSValue is released. The only thing the documentation says about the pointer stored in an NSValue is:

> If you create an NSValue object with an allocated data item, don’t
>   deallocate its memory while the NSValue object exists.

The main reason for using an NSValue is to box a value so that it can be placed into an NSArray or similar collection which only accept objects.  It wouldn't make sense for the memory to be freed simply because the NSValue box is no longer needed.